# 12345678910111213.......201520162017, what is the remainder when this number is divided by 11?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A number is written this way :
12345678910111213.......201520162017, what is the remainder when this number is divided by 11?

What I've thought of is discuss them in group.

So I got

1~9:odd digits sum:25, even digits sum:20

10~99: odd digits:45*9, even digits:45*10

100~999: observe that each hundred digit and tenth digit of each three digit number can be 
eliminated.

Then I am stuck here. Cause there are thousands of four-digit numbers behind and they can not be eliminated.
Is there any other more convenient way to solve this question?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The portion of $4$-digit numbers is $2017+2016\cdot 10^4+...+1000\cdot 10^{4\cdot1017}$. The remainder of $10^4$ after division by $11$ is $1$. Therefore, this sum gives the same remainder as $2017+2016+...+1000=\frac{3017\cdot 1018}{2}$, which gives remainder $9$. You could do the other portions also this way, instead of the alternating sum of the digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align}N:=123456\dots 20162017&=
10^{6952}\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot 10^{9-k}
+10^{6772} \sum_{k=10}^{99} k 10^{2(99-k)}\\
&\qquad+10^{4072} \sum_{k=100}^{999} k10^{3(999-k)}+
\sum_{k=1000}^{2017} k10^{4(2017-k)}.
\end{align}$$
Now we evaluate $N$ modulo $11$, (and therefore $(10)^n\equiv (-1)^n \pmod{11}$),
$$N\equiv -\sum_{k=1}^9 k\cdot (-1)^{k}+ \sum_{k=10}^{99} k -\sum_{k=100}^{999} k(-1)^{k}+\sum_{k=1000}^{2017} k.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wouldn't the reversed number be $71026102...987654321$?

Comment: @supinf Now it should be correct. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @supunf What do you mean, please?